# Who introduced the idea of Hilbert Spaces in physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, soft-question, history, specific-reference

I'm looking for the foundational paper / book that connected Quantum Mechanics and Hilbert spaces.

EDIT: I've just read the first chapter of Neumann's "Mathematical Foundations Of Quantum Mechanics". At this point I'm almost convinced that he was the first one to mention Hilbert Spaces in Quantum Mechanics.
I'll update the question when I have more info about the other papers.
[image]

Comment: Heisenberg, Born, Jordan (cf. [Matrix Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics)), later formalised by Dirac, von Neumann, etc.

Comment: If you don’t find an answer here, you may try [hsm.se]

Comment: Von Neumann invented the name Hilbert Space (not Hilbert himself) and also applied them to QM, so he probably takes priority. "Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics", 1932.

Comment: I'm reading all the recommended papers / books above. I'll post the answer shortly if I find it.